# Wikimedia with Parsoid 0.4.0 doesn't start or doesn't connect properly with nodejs

Tags: parsoid

I have parsoid 0.4.0 from mediawiki, nodejs v0.10.25, when I /etc/init.d/parsoid start, I receive workers restarting having the next messages in the parsoid.log, this message is repeated indefinitely, making my parsoid.log growing indefinitely, another hand I don't recerive any response at http://localhost:8142, 8142 is the port where my parsoid says is serving when I start with "/etc/init.d/parsoid start with the output message:

```
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib# /etc/init.d/parsoid start
Started Parsoid server on port 8142
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib#
```

/var/log/parsoid.log output :

```
[info][master][13876] initializing 4 workers
[info][worker][13879] loading ...
[info][worker][13882] loading ...
[info][worker][13878] loading ...
[info][worker][13881] loading ...
[fatal][worker][13879] uncaught exception Object function     createApplication() {
var app = function(req, res, next) {
app.handle(req, res, next);
};

mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
mixin(app, proto, false);

app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
app.init();
return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
var app = function(req, res, next) {
app.handle(req, res, next);
};

mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
mixin(app, proto, false);

app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
app.init();
return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
at new ParsoidService (/usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/ParsoidService.js:23:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js:202:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

On another hand I can see de processes started with "ps -ef | grep parsoid", de pids of the processes change everytime as you can see with the next output like:

```
parsoid    920     1  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/nodejs             /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js >>         /var/log/parsoid/parsoid.log 2>&1
parsoid    949   920  0 09:08 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2563   949 18 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2565   949 19 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2567   949 17 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2569   949  5 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
root      2572  2134  0 09:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto parsoid
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/var/log/parsoid# ps -ef| grep parsoid
parsoid    920     1  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js >>     /var/log/parsoid/parsoid.log 2>&1
parsoid    949   920  0 09:08 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2579   949 23 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2581   949 23 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2583   949  0 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2585   949  0 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
root      2588  2134  0 09:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto parsoid
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/var/log/parsoid# ps -ef| grep parsoid
parsoid    920     1  0 09:08 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js >>     /var/log/parsoid/parsoid.log 2>&1
parsoid    949   920  0 09:08 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2581   949 22 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2583   949 30 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2585   949 28 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
parsoid   2589   949 15 09:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/nodejs     /usr/lib/parsoid/src/api/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js
```

I show the /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/settings.js aswell:

```
exports.setup = function(parsoidConfig) {
    // Set your own user-agent string
    // Otherwise, defaults to "Parsoid/<current-version-defined-in-    package.json>"
    //parsoidConfig.userAgent = "My-User-Agent-String";

    // The URL of your MediaWiki API endpoint.
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi('localhost', {uri:     'http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php'} );
    // To specify a proxy (or proxy headers) specific to this prefix (which
    // overrides defaultAPIProxyURI) use:
    /*
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi('localhost', {
            uri: 'http://localhost/w/api.php',
            // set `proxy` to `null` to override and force no proxying.
            proxy: {
                    uri: 'http://my.proxy:1234/',
                    headers: { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' } // headers are     optional
            }
    });
    */
......
......
......
```

Here I show the packets installed and the version of my ubuntu server:

```
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib#
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib#
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib# dpkg -l parsoid
Deseado=Desconocido/Instalar/Eliminar/Purgar/Retener
| Estado=No/Instalado/Config-files/Desempaquetado/Medio-conf/Medio-    inst/espera-disparo/pendiente-disparo
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/Requiere-reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo)
||/ Nombre                            Versión               Arquitectura              Descripción
+++-=================================-=====================-        =====================-    =======================================================================
ii  parsoid                           0.4.0                 amd64                     Web service converting HTML+RDFa to MediaWiki wikitext and back
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib# dpkg -l nodejs
Deseado=Desconocido/Instalar/Eliminar/Purgar/Retener
| Estado=No/Instalado/Config-files/Desempaquetado/Medio-conf/Medio-    inst/espera-disparo/pendiente-disparo
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/Requiere-reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo)
||/ Nombre                            Versión               Arquitectura              Descripción
+++-=================================-=====================-    =====================-    =======================================================================
ii  nodejs                            0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu amd64                     evented I/O for V8 javascript
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib# dpkg -l nodejs-legacy
Deseado=Desconocido/Instalar/Eliminar/Purgar/Retener
| Estado=No/Instalado/Config-files/Desempaquetado/Medio-conf/Medio-    inst/espera-disparo/pendiente-disparo
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/Requiere-reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo)
||/ Nombre                            Versión               Arquitectura                  Descripción
+++-=================================-=====================-        =====================-        =======================================================================
ii  nodejs-legacy                     0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu all                            evented I/O for V8 javascript (legacy symlink)
root@vscj016mlinuxserver:/usr/lib#
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a much better time with a newer version of Node, for example >=4.3. You can use NVM to run manage different versions of Node: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 0):

This is my parsoid configuration , I don't Know if this is the problema:

```
exports.setup = function(parsoidConfig) {
    // Set your own user-agent string
    // Otherwise, defaults to "Parsoid/<current-version-defined-in-    package.json>"
    //parsoidConfig.userAgent = "My-User-Agent-String";

    // The URL of your MediaWiki API endpoint.
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi('localhost', {     uri: 'http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php' });
    // To specify a proxy (or proxy headers) specific to this prefix (which
    // overrides defaultAPIProxyURI) use:
    /*
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi('localhost', {
            uri: 'http://localhost/w/api.php',
            // set `proxy` to `null` to override and force no proxying.
            proxy: {
                    uri: 'http://my.proxy:1234/',
                    headers: { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' } // headers     are optional
            }
    });
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this my /etc/mediawiki/parsoid configuration:

exports.setup = function(parsoidConfig) {
    // Set your own user-agent string
    // Otherwise, defaults to "Parsoid/<current-version-defined-in-    package.json>"
    //parsoidConfig.userAgent = "My-User-Agent-String";

    // The URL of your MediaWiki API endpoint.
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi('localhost', { uri: 'http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php' });
    // To specify a proxy (or proxy headers) specific to this prefix (which
    // overrides defaultAPIProxyURI) use:
    /*
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi('localhost', {
            uri: 'http://localhost/w/api.php',
            // set `proxy` to `null` to override and force no proxying.
            proxy: {
                    uri: 'http://my.proxy:1234/',
                    headers: { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' } // headers are optional
            }
    });
    */
```